# Java set and get method if statement

Tags: java, methods, get, set

I have this main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rec 
{


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        rectangle myRectangle = new rectangle();
        float w;
        float h;
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the width of the rectangle");
        w = input.nextFloat();
        myRectangle.setWidth(w);
        //if(myRectangle.width)


        System.out.println("Please enter the height of the rectangle");
        h = input.nextFloat();
        myRectangle.setHeight(h);


        System.out.println("The Perimeter of a rectanle having height of " +myRectangle.height + " and width of " + myRectangle.width + " is " + myRectangle.FindPerimeter());
        //System.out.println(myRectangle.width);
        //System.out.println(myRectangle.FindPerimeter());
        //System.out.println(myRectangle.FindArea());
    }


}
```

And I have this rectangle class below. How can I code it so that when user inputs a number more than 20 or less than 0, the program will ask user to input again? Here is the rectangle class:

```
package rec;


public class rectangle 
{

        float width=1;
        float height=1;
        float perimeter;

        public void setWidth(float w)
        {
           if(w<20 && w>0)
               width = w;
           else
           {
               System.out.println("invalid entry, please try again: ");
               //setWidth(w);
           }    
        }


        public void setHeight(float h)
        {
           if(h<20 && h>0)
               height = h;
           else
           {
               System.out.println("invalid entry, please try again: ");
               //setWidth(h);
           }
        }




        public float getWidth()
        {
           return width;
        }
        public float getHeight()
        {
           return height;
        }
        public float FindPerimeter()
        {
           return (width+height)*2;
        }

        public float FindArea()
        {
           return width*height;
        }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `setHeight` return a `boolean` to indicate whether the height is valid is one possible solution.  There are a couple of disadvantages, though:

(1) If you forget to check the result when you call `setHeight`, your program will think everything is fine when in fact the `setHeight` failed.  This is too easy to do in Java, because you can call a method and throw away the result:

```
setHeight(40.0);
// keep going as if everything were hunky dory
```

(2) If I'm not mistaken, there are some frameworks that expect "setter" methods to have void results.  I think this is in the definition of a "bean".

My approach would be to add methods to test for validity:

```
public class rectangle 
{
    float width=1;
    float height=1;
    float perimeter;

    public boolean isValidWidth(float w) {
       return (w < 20 && w > 0);
    }

    public void setWidth(float w)
    {
       if(isValidWidth(w)) {
           width = w;
       } else {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid width");
       }
    }

    // and similarly for height

}
```

Then the calling code would become something like:

```
boolean done = false;
while(!done) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the width of the rectangle");
    w = input.nextFloat();
    done = myRectangle.isValidWidth(w); 
}
myRectangle.setWidth(w);
```

or

```
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter the width of the rectangle");
    w = input.nextFloat();
} while (!myRectangle.isValidWidth(w));  // keep going as long as width is *not* valid
myRectangle.setWidth(w);
```

The `throw` is there in case the program forgets to do the validity check first.  If the caller tries to call `setWidth(w)` and `w` is invalid, the program will not just continue on as if everything were OK.  Instead, the program would die on an exception (or would catch the exception somewhere else).

But both of these solutions put the validity check inside `rectangle` where it belongs; so I think both are better than requiring the caller to know what the bounds are.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it in your setter. If you do you are mixing your "model" and your "input" in one class, so if you want to change it (say to read from a file) it's much harder.

Change your calling code:

```
h = -1;
while(h < 0 || h > 20) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the height of the rectangle");
    h = input.nextFloat();
}
myRectangle.setHeight(h);
```

The other approach would be to try setting the height and have the function return true on success or false on failure - this way all the validation is in the one place

```
bool done = false;
while(!done) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the height of the rectangle");
    h = input.nextFloat();
    done = myRectangle.setHeight(h);
}

public bool setHeight(float h)
{
   bool ok = false;
   if(h<20 && h>0) {
       height = h;
       ok = true;
   }
   return ok;
}
```

Comment: Minor nit: `bool` is C++.  Java uses `boolean`.